# Is it possible to manually set JMS properties when using WMQ API?

Tags: java, .net, jms, ibm-mq

I have traditional (`com.ibm.mq.jar`) MQ application in Java for testing purpose. Now I need to use that application to send some messages to JMS. When I try to set any JMS property on MQ message, for example:

```
message.setStringProperty("JMSDestination", "queue:///" + queueName);
```

I always get error: 2471 - `MQRC_PROPERTY_NOT_AVAILABLE`. It works if I just remove `JMS` from the property name.

Is it possible to set JMS properties directly on `MQMessage`? What is a correct way to do that on MQ level?

Btw. I have the same application in .NET where setting JMS properties this way is possible so I'm only trying to use the same code in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not allowed to do this manually. Please use the JMS API to set JMS properties.

Restrictions to MQ properties are explained [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.csqzal.doc/fg20140_.htm).

One thing is interessting in that document page though,

> The names of properties specified directly as MQRFH2 elements are not guaranteed to be validated by the MQPUT call.

You could perhaps work around this, on a short term basis. There seems to be no guarantee that setting the MQRFH2 elements directly will not be validated, though.

Comment: It is really annoying when you have two same APIs (just for different platforms) from the same vendor and each of that APIs behave differently - according to your link, it looks like .NET API violates these rules. Btw. how to set MQRFH2 elements directly in Java - does it mean that I must code myself RFH structure and put it into message content?

Comment: Yes, but so it seems to be. You are right, you need to add the RFH2 area yourself and populate it. There is some small lib to do such things http://code.google.com/p/wmq-util/wiki/CreatingRfh2Header on google code. You might have use for it or get inspired by the code (it's rather tiny).